# PHP: Missing euro sign while converting iso-8859-1 to utf-8

Tags: php, xpath, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I read an external html file which is iso-8859-1, but also displays the euro sign.

Header of html file:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
```

I want to convert this file to UTF-8, but then the euro sign get lost.
I know that iso-8859-1 normally doesn't support the euro sign. But however the originally source also displays it.

Here's my code simplified:

```html
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

 $htmlSource    = file_get_contents($url); 


 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 @$doc->loadHTML($htmlSource);
  
 $domXPath = new DOMXPath($doc);
 $agbText = $domXPath->evaluate('string('.$xPath.')');

 echo $agbText;

?>
```

The upper code opens the external file and get a specific part of it via xpath. Everything is working except that the euro sign is missing.
I already tried methods like mb_convert_encoding() and iconv() without success.

One fix which works is:

```html
    <?php
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');

     $htmlSource    = file_get_contents($url); 


     $doc = new DOMDocument();
     @$doc->loadHTML($htmlSource);
      
     $domXPath = new DOMXPath($doc);
     $agbText = $domXPath->evaluate('string('.$xPath.')');

     utf8_decode($agbText)

    ?>
```

But i need UTF-8 in the header as charset. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: As you say, the euro sign is not present in the iso-8859-1 repertoire. So how is it represented in this HTML document?

Comment: I dont understand how your fix works. Trying to convert € from utf8 to latin-1 using utf8_decode will output a ? character. Something else is going on here.  Are you using &euro;

Comment: In the html document it's represented correctly as '€'.  You can view the source here: https://secure.traveltainment.de/booking/agb.php?KID=689000&ordner_name=holidaycheck&statistik_tag=holidaycheck&vacode=FLYD_Sommer

Comment: I think the external source actually uses ISO-8859-15(euro sign included). I don't know why the meta tag is wrong. But as a result the solution is: header('Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15');